# Add User to Group 'Root' in Slackware

Tags: permissions, user-permissions, slackware

I have a user xyzong and I want it to grant root permission. How will I add her in a group 'Root' in Slackware 14.2? Slackware documentation is so rare, so please help. Thanks.

Comment: This question seems more fit for ServerFault than for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

To add user xyzong to group root ran as root:

```
# usermod -aG root xyzong
```

See "man usermod" for additional info.

But don't know why.